# How can i make delay in typescript?

Tags: html, angular, angular-material, spinner

first of all in using angular. Im having issue with login component which i want to show a spinner for some secs after the user enter the details and get response from server... right now everything happen fast and im not able to see the spinner for like 7 secs like i want to.. how can i delay the app so i can see it? here is my code:

component:

```
 showSpinner: boolean = false;

  showMySpinner() {
  this.showSpinner = true;
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.showSpinner = false;
  }, 7000);
  }

  constructor(private dataService: DataService, private auth: AuthService, 
  public matService: MatService) { }

  loginUser(username, password, type): void {

  switch (type.value) {

  case "ADMIN": {
    this.dataService.getLoginResponse(username.value, password.value, 
     type.value).subscribe(res => {
      **this.showMySpinner();** HERE I USE THE FUNCTION BUT IT GOES RIGHT UNDER IT AND DONT LET IT SHOW
      this.auth.updateUserType(type.value);
      sessionStorage.setItem("type", "ADMIN");
      sessionStorage.setItem("username", username.value);
      this.matService.openSnackBar(this.loginSuccess, "success");
    }, error => this.matService.openSnackBar(this.loginFailed, "error"));
    break;
    }
```

html:

```
<mat-spinner [style.display]="showSpinner ? 'block' : 'none'"></mat-spinner>
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rxjs delay`.

You may add `delay` to `getLoginResponse()` method in `DataService` itself. And toggle the spinner accordingly in component file.

data.service.ts

```
import {delay} from 'rxjs/operators'

getLoginResponse() {
  return this.http.get(url).pipe(delay(7000));
}
```

component.ts

```
switch (type.value) {
 case "ADMIN": {
    this.showSpinner = true; // start spinner just before asynchronous request is sent
    this.dataService.getLoginResponse(username.value, password.value, 
     type.value).subscribe(res => {
      this.showSpinner = false; // stop spinner
      this.auth.updateUserType(type.value);
      sessionStorage.setItem("type", "ADMIN");
      sessionStorage.setItem("username", username.value);
      this.matService.openSnackBar(this.loginSuccess, "success");
    }, error => this.matService.openSnackBar(this.loginFailed, "error"));
    break;
}
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/observable-delay?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: im gettting "Property "delay" does not exist on type "Observable<Object>.. something isd wrong with the import

Comment: Sorry I forgot to include `pipe`. `this.http.get(url).pipe(delay(7000));`

Comment: Check updated https://stackblitz.com/edit/observable-delay?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts This utilizes `http.get()` and adds a delay. Updated answer with demo link

Comment: @אוראלהינדי If this helped, please mark the answer as solved.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initiate your spinner before your call.

```
this.showSpinner = true;
this.dataService.getLoginResponse(username.value, password.value, 
     type.value).subscribe(res => {
      this.showSpinner = false;
      ...
    }, error => this.matService.openSnackBar(this.loginFailed, "error"));
    break;
```

Comment: Then you can put your timout where `this.showSpinner = false;` is.
But what is the purpose of seeing it? Is it just for you to see if it works? Else, The user normaly doesnt need to see thhe spinner after the login is completed.

Comment: i want the user to see it for something like 5 secs after he press the login button and get response from the server.. just for styling.. i dont want the user to see it before pressing the login button

Comment: So, in you click button function, First, you will have `this.showSpinner = false`.
And then, when you fetch your user, you can have  `this.showSpinner = true`

Comment: TRIED IT NO LUCK